# Sass: printing prefix in @keyframe animation inside an @each

Tags: sass

I'm trying to print a prefix inside a each @keyframes in order to save code:

```scss
// browsers prefix list
$browsers-prefix: "", "-moz-", "-webkit-";

@mixin generate-pulse($id, $initial-size, $grow: 20px) {
  // vars
  $animation-effect: ease-in-out;
  $animation-time: 2.5s;

  width: $initial-size;
  height: $initial-size;

  @each $prefix in $browsers-prefix {
    #{$prefix}animation: #{$id}-pulse
      $animation-time
      infinite
      $animation-effect;

    @#{$prefix}keyframes #{$id}-pulse {
      0% {
        width: $initial-size;
        height: $initial-size;
      }

      50% {
        width: $initial-size + $grow;
        height: $initial-size + $grow;
      }

      100% {
        width: $initial-size;
        height: $initial-size;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this for some reason is working good in codepen, but is not working in my project:

[image]

How can I fix those errors? Maybe my issue is printing the values in that way.

Comment: Just a note, but unless you are targeting IE8 or below, you don't need the prefixes (for keyframes, and almost nothing these days). If you do, it might be better to let a library like PostCSS handle them for you, and not SASS anymore. To solve your issue, though, I recall using `#{unquote( "" )}` in SASS to output whatever a string generates without trying to be clever?

Comment: I know, but I'm working in a company where some customers are using old browser versions. Regarding the unquote, how would you apply that? could you give me an example? thanks.

Comment: if I replace `@#{$prefix}keyframes` by `@keyframes` it works. The issue is between the `@` and `#` I guess.

Comment: Ok is solved, the application is using an old sass compiler version I guess. This feature was added after, more information here: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/429